# htaccess - Script inside subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have already one blog running in root folder and I want to test another one in a sub directory called "test".

How do I **make all links point to example.com/test/login.php and not example.com/login.php** ? I don't want to edit all links in my files, I want this one behave as root so later no need to change anything when I put it in production.
I assume it can be fixed with .htaccess crazy Rewrite Module but I haven't figured it out yet so please help save my time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /test/ [NC] 
RewriteRule !^test/ /test%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Yes, that works great except that I want to use the root folder web too. Now everything goes to that sub directory...

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. It's not folder called "web", it's just that another script runs in root folder and another one in that sub directory "test". Like all pages referred by site.com/test go to site.com/test/nextthing and not site.com/nextthing

Comment: Ok edited and removed web. But in your question you wrote: `I want this one behave as root` Which is how it is. Now what is not clear to me which URLs you want to send to `root` and which ones to `root/test`.

Comment: Hyperlinks clicked in root (public_html) folder should behave normally but links clicked in test (public_html/test) folder should be redirected to site.com/test/clicked_link.php and not site.com/clicked_link.php. Using header function also should behave same way.

Comment: Ah ok that might be bit tricky, let me test something before I edit my answer.

Comment: Ok check the edit now. And make sure there is no `.htaccess` file in test directory.